# ComboBox & SelectedItem setting on dropdown opening

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a ComboBox control of DropDown type which contains items "Vx", "V", "G", "g".

Edit field text is "V" ([image] :)

**The problem is**: when I open dropdown list, item "Vx" highlighted as selected, not "V". So I assume combobox uses FindString to find SelectedItem - so search result is equivalent to first matched item by case-insensitive string.StartsWith.

**The question is**: how I can override this behaviour to find full-matched item? I need case-sensitive search with full equivalent of strings, not only StartsWith. For entered "V" i need item "V" (not "Vx") to be selected when combobox dropdown list is opening.

Thank you for replies.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to type in the combo box? If not, change the `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList`.